# EF4 Generic Entity ID

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have an address table that is like as follows:

Address

- int address_id
- string street1
- string street2
- ... other address fields ...
- int entity_id
- int entity_type_id
- datetime created_at
- datetime updated_at
- datetime deleted_at

The intention is to allow other entities (like person, supplier, office, etc).

My problem is that I cannot foreign key the entity_id to the tables that represent the other entities and therefore I am at lost as how how I can use entity framework to have associations / navigation properties.

I think i could put a entity table in the system and have every other entity derive from this but I am not sure this would not cause unnessecary difficulties later on.

Can anyone suggest an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with current EF version. EF uses same rules like FK relation in database so if you cannot make it in database you also cannot make it in EF. You will not have navigation property but you can still use manual join in Linq-to-entities query.